# How to pass columns as a JSON record to the API method using Pyspark?

Tags: api, rest, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset where I segregate the records in `4K batch` for a DF and then try to hit the API. The first part is working fine. The problem occurs when I try to hit the API. I want to hit the API in the form of `JSON` records. Therefore, I am passing a struct of values converted as JSON to the `call_to_cust_bulk_api` method. Inside that method, I pass to a `custRequestBody` and then send that data to the API. The code is below:

```
def call_to_cust_bulk_api(url, payload):
    print("Calling Bulk API")
    try:
        print(payload)
        token = get_token(tokenUrl, tokenBody)
        custRequestBody = {
            "Token": token,
            "CustomerName": "",
            "Object": "",
            "Data": payload
        }
        # TODO: write code...
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        print(":::::::jsn load::::")
        response = requests.post(url, data=custRequestBody, headers=headers)
        print(":::Response::::", response)
        data = response.json()
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print('ExceptionInPushing ' + str(e))
          
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(
    ".csv",
    sep="~")

df = df.withColumn("uniqueID", lit("1"))

df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy(col("uniqueID")).orderBy(col("uniqueID"))
))  

total_count = df.count()  

i = 1
while i < total_count:
    rangeNum = i + 3999
    print("Range Num:::")
    print(rangeNum)
    df1 = df.filter((col("row_num") >= i) & (col("row_num") <= rangeNum))
    finalDF = df1.drop("row_num", "edl_timestamp", "uniqueID")
    colsListToBePassed = finalDF.columns
    print("finalDF count:::", finalDF.count())

    finalDF = finalDF.repartition(finalDF.rdd.getNumPartitions()).withColumn("status_for_batch",
                                                                             call_to_cust_bulk_api(policyUrl,
                                                                                                              to_json(
                                                                                                                  struct(*colsListToBePassed))))
```

It gives me the below `error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lumiq/IdeaProjects/pyspark_python_test/com/apitest3.py", line 116, in <module>
    finalDF = finalDF.repartition(finalDF.rdd.getNumPartitions()).withColumn("status_for_batch",
  File "/home/lumiq/Downloads/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2477, in withColumn
    raise TypeError("col should be Column")
TypeError: col should be Column
```

So, I want to track the `response` as a `new column` and write this data frame later.

So, where am I going wrong?